# Wordpress / WooCommerce - Product Image has no Link to Add

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I'm new to Wordpress. I installed the Livre Theme and WooCommerce.

In the Edit Product screen, there is an option to add a Back Cover Image. But, unlike the other fields which have a link at the bottom to say 'Add Product Image' or 'Add Product Gallery Images' the Back Cover Image section has no link.

Can anyone advise me on how to fix this. I have tried contacting the Theme Creator but got no response.

Here's a screenshot showing the problem:

[image: Screenshot showing missing link]

Here's what I've tried:

I've uploaded the dummy content for this theme and what's really bizarre is, when you view this product (see screenshot) the back cover is there. I have no idea where it's getting it from or why it's not there on the product page when the front cover and look inside are.

I've looked everywhere through all the settings and can't figure out why the link is missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without testing the theme. There are 2 possibilities that I can think of. 1: Metabox inside the box is hidden with CSS conflicts, so the link for the upload button is there but you can't see it due to CSS conflict. 2: Metabox is only pages and posts but theme author showing meta box for all the post type but not showing the content inside metabox only for specific post type.

Comment: @VijayHardaha Can't thank you enough Vijay. Been staring at this for three days, trying all sorts of things. Can finally get going again and it was really urgent - losing money every day without the website progressing - so I'm so grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VijayHardaha for his comment which enabled me to get to the bottom of this.

I disabled all the plugins then re-enabled them one-by-one (it should have occurred to me to try this but I'm new to website development).

I found the conflict with Elementor. As soon as you disable that plugin, the Back Cover Link appears.

Not an actual solution (I have no idea how to resolve the conflict) but it's a useful workaround.

Disable Elementor, Add your Back Cover Image and if you want to continue using Elementor, re-enable it. The Back Cover Image remains, it's only the link to change it that disappears.